# JBOSS SEAM Excel date cell

Tags: excel, jboss, cell, seam

I have a cell that is displaying a date. I would like to add hours and minutes to the date being displayed, which, according to the jboss documentation, should be possible. I've tried a few variations to force the cell to display HH:mm with the m/d/y but have had no luck and haven't found much after googling. I am wondering if anyone else has had a similar experience or knows a solution. If there is any more information I can provide, I will!!

A variation of what I've tried..

```
<e:cell templates="tableCellTemplate"
                value="#{pivotRow.statusEntryDate}" forceType="date" mask="FORMAT9" style="xls-format-mask: FORMAT9" />
```

Comment: I also tried mask="mm-dd-yyyy HH:mm"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know there exist a tag for this: "convertDateTime", maybe it could help.
This is how it works:

```
<ui:composition xmlns:s="http://jboss.com/products/seam/taglib"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

 <h:outputText value="#{pivotRow.statusEntryDate}">
   <s:convertDateTime pattern="MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss a z" />
 </h:outputText>
```

Here are the specs about 
[convertDateTime](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_convertDateTime.html)

I used it with outputText tag as you can see, but maybe it works in your cell tag.

Comment: Thanks for this information. I get <f:convertDateTime> Parent not an instance of ValueHolder because the cells are not a jsf component so I'm not sure how to get around this. Thank you though!!

Comment: I think this would be the best solution but doesn't work for SEAM's excel stuff. I ended up converting the date to a string in the java code.